# Why is 'withColumn' taking so long in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe containing 1000 columns and 10,000 records(rows).
I need to create 2000 more columns, by performing some computation on the existing columns.

```
df #pyspark dataframe contaning 1000 columns and 10,000 records
df = df.withColumn('C1001', ((df['C269'] * df['C285'])/df['C41'])) #existing column names range from C1 to C1000
df = df.withColumn('C1002', ((df['C4'] * df['C267'])/df['C146']))
df = df.withColumn('C1003', ((df['C87'] * df['C134'])/df['C238']))
.
.
.
df = df.withColumn('C3000', ((df['C365'] * df['C235'])/df['C321']))
```

The issue is, this takes way too long, around 45 minutes or so.
Since I am a newbie, I was wondering what I am doing wrong?
P.S.: I am running spark on databricks, with 1 driver and 1 worker node, both having 16GB Memory and 8 Cores.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of what you're doing is just creating an execution plan.  Spark is lazy executing until there's an action that triggers it.  So the 45 minutes that you're seeing is probably from executing all the transformations that you've been setting up.

If you want to see how long a single withColumn takes, then trigger an action like df.count() or something before, and then do a single withColumn and then another df.count() (to trigger action again).

Take a look more into pyspark execution plan, transformations and actions.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve the timings for these transformations?

Comment: You can try sprinkle actions here and there to keep the execution plan complexity down, sometime that can help.  If you have the option of scaling up your cluster (increase more nodes or cpu cores) and increase the number of executors, and then repartition your data so that you can get more parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

Without being too specific

- and looking at the observations of the 1st answer

  - and knowing that Execution Plans for many DF-columns aka "very wide data" are costly to  compute

    - a move to RDD processing may well be the path to take.

Answer (score -1):

**Do this in single line rather than doing it one by one**

```
df = df.withColumn('C1001', COl1).df.withColumn('C1002', COl2).df.withColumn('C1003', COl3) ......
```

Comment: Is that better? Wouldn't it result in the same execution plan

Comment: this will end up with the same performance issues.